# Redirect .htaccess Using question mark Still not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect a specific page :

```
http://olddomain.com/index.php?p=70 to http://newdomain.com/newpage.php
```

i try to create .htaccess like this but still not working :

```
Redirect 301 /index.php?p=70 http://newdomain.com/newpage.php
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index.php\?p=70\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/newpage.php? [L,R]
```